# Leaflet.Draw Custom Wavy Path for Rectangle

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

How can I apply a custom path style to a rectangle in Leaflet.draw? I've been playing around with the CSS and can style it but I can't do anything more than using stroke-width, stroke-dasharray etc. We are building a map that allows people to tag photos and want to implement a "photo frame" kind of feel such as this. Is it possible?[image]

Comment: Do you mean adding photos with that frame around, or just the frame with transparent center? All vector shapes in Leaflet are implemented in SVG or Canvas. If you can find a way to draw your frame using SVG or Canvas, you can convert a vector (whether from Leaflet.draw or anything else) to your frame.

Comment: Just the frame, I've already got the images showing up as SVGs but need to apply a frame around it. If I can draw the frame using SVG, how can I set my shape to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it that way for example:

1. Once user draws a rectangle, retrieve the rectangle dimensions. Look for [`"draw:created"` event](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#drawcreated).
2. Generate the code for the custom SVG frame based on these dimensions.
3. Insert the SVG onto the map (possibly replacing the Leaflet.draw rectangle), similarly to an Image Overlay.

For the last step, you would probably need to slightly modify the `L.imageOverlay` code so that it adds an SVG container rather than an image, but there should not be any difficulty in doing so.

You might be interested in:

- [Is it possible to stretch a imageOverlay in leaflet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891230/is-it-possible-to-stretch-a-imageoverlay-in-leaflet) (but looks like it uses an SVG in a file, not dynamically generated)
- [How can I make a custom SVG overlay on Leaflet without using D3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962996/how-can-i-make-a-custom-svg-overlay-on-leaflet-without-using-d3) (no answer)

If your custom SVG frame does not need to be dynamically generated (i.e. you can export it into an independent file, and it auto adjusts its "waves" based on its displayed size), then the standard Image Overlay could even be enough.